# Force ag-grid floating filter to only accept numbers in input

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using ag-grid enterprise and I would like to apply floating filters for all my columns. Sometimes the filter can be alphanumeric but in other cases it should only accept numbers.

I tried to manage this following this example from the ag-grid doc:

```
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'age',
            filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                allowedCharPattern: '\\d\\-\\,', 
                numberParser: text => {
                    return text == null ? null : parseFloat(text.replace(',', '.'));
                }
            }
        }
    ],

    // other grid options ...
}
```

but it doesn't work... I was wondering if an extra configuration is needed for the `allowedCharPattern` to work.

This is how a colDef looks like in my project:

```
{
                    ...commonProperties,
                    field: column.fieldName,
                    suppressSizeToFit: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    minWidth: getMinWidth(column.fieldName),
                    width: column.colWidth,
                    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
                    floatingFilter: true,
                    floatingFilterComponentParams: {
                        suppressFilterButton: true,
                    },
                    filterParams: {
                        allowedCharPattern: '\\d\\-\\,',
                        numberParser: (text) => {
                            return text == null
                                ? null
                                : parseFloat(text.replace(',', '.'))
                        },
                    },
                }
```

Am I missing something?
thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

- Use "agNumberColumnFilter" instead of "agNumberColumnFilter"
- Please check if you are using latest version of ag grid. It was not working for me on older version. It started working after upgrading to latest version 27.2.0